# Several "App Group" Errors when going to Google Maps app from Google Maps iOS SDK but only the first time

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios, url-scheme, ios-app-group

I have the Google Maps SDK added and all of the mapping is working fine. The problem is that the first time the app is launched/installed if I navigate to the native Google Maps app via my own button or the "Google" logo I get a slew of "App Group" errors:

2021-05-10 16:07:18.437249-0400 MapTest2[9109:1860098] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier: client is not entitled
2021-05-10 16:07:18.439 MapTest2[9109/0x16e1bf000] [lvl=3] -[GMSx_GIPPseudonymousIDStore initializeStorage] Shared App Groups unavailable
2021-05-10 16:07:20.655312-0400 MapTest2[9109:1860243] [unspecified] container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier: client is not entitled
2021-05-10 16:07:20.656 MapTest2[9109/0x16e01b000] [lvl=3] -[GMSx_GIPPseudonymousIDStore initializeStorage] Shared App Groups unavailable

It does not cause a crash but in the case of opening the Google Maps app for directions, it prevents the directions process from starting, I just get a constant loading spinner in the bottom bar.
Now if I close and run the app again, it works fine when use the Google links, no errors and everything works.
I do not have any App Groups, even on a dirt simple project it does the same thing. Adding the App Groups entitlements has no effect. Using a manual URL scheme link in a blank project works fine as well, the issue only seems to arise when using the links from a project with the Google Maps SDK installed.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with - GoogleMaps (5.2.0). @Notsileous did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I added a bug report and they accepted it and assigned it but last I knew it was still unresolved. I still get the "errors" but I do not consistently get the map loading issue. I started using "universal links" instead and it works much better. Start with https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1 and add your post data "&destination=" , "&travelmode=", etc. Instead of the "comgoogle" nonsense.